# Error while accessing Flask config while testing

Tags: python, testing, flask, config

While writing tests for my Flask app I came across an issue when trying to set Flask config settings.

Usually, I do it like this:

```
import unittest

from factory import create_app


class ConfigTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app = create_app('flask_test.cfg')
        app.testing = True
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_app_is_development(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.app.config['SECRET_KEY'] is 'secret_key')
        self.assertTrue(self.app.config['DEBUG'] is True)
```

This resulted in an error

> AttributeError: 'FlaskClient' object has no attribute 'config'

Only from debugging I saw that there was no "config" attribute instead I had to go `self.app.application.config` to get it to work.

```
import unittest

from factory import create_app


class ConfigTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app = create_app('flask_test.cfg')
        app.testing = True
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_app_is_development(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.app.application.config['SECRET_KEY'] is 'secret_key')
        self.assertTrue(self.app.application.config['DEBUG'] is True)
```

Am I doing something, did Flask change this in an update or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Incorrectly posted code in the top block, it's correct now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `app` in production is of type `flask.app.Flask` while the one you use in testing is `flask.testing.FlaskClient` which are 2 different objects. The way you access the config by using `self.app.application.config` is the correct and only way as i beilive when you set `self.app = app.test_client()` this returns a FlaskClient instance.

take a look at the flowing: [FlaskClient](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.testing.FlaskClient) and [test_client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.test_client)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip that you can do when testing the client itself:

```
import unittest
from app import app


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    # setup client
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    # generating proposital error to see methods available by self.client
    def test_app_configs(self):
        print(dir(self.client))
        self.assertEqual(False, True)
```

So doing `py.test` in terminal, this results in:

```
self = <test_app.Tests testMethod=test_if_inside_aws>

    def test_app_configs(self):
        print(dir(self.client))
>       self.assertEqual(False, True)
E       AssertionError: False != True

src/test_app.py:29: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ---------------------------------------------------
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'allow_subdomain_redirects', 'application', 'cookie_jar', 'delete', 'delete_cookie', 'environ_base', 'get', 'head', 'open', 'options', 'patch', 'post', 'preserve_context', 'put', 'resolve_redirect', 'response_wrapper', 'run_wsgi_app', 'session_transaction', 'set_cookie', 'trace']
================================================= short test summary info ==================================================
FAILED src/test_app.py::Tests::test_app_configs - AssertionError: False != True
```

As @gyx-hh mentioned above, there's a `application` method available for the `self.client`. Now, doing the same process but now for checking methods for `self.client.application`:

```
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_before_request_lock', '_blueprint_order', '_find_error_handler', '_get_exc_class_and_code', '_got_first_request', '_register_error_handler', '_static_folder', '_static_url_path', 'add_template_filter', 'add_template_global', 'add_template_test', 'add_url_rule', 'after_request', 'after_request_funcs', 'app_context', 'app_ctx_globals_class', 'auto_find_instance_path', 'before_first_request', 'before_first_request_funcs', 'before_request', 'before_request_funcs', 'blueprints', 'cli', 'config', 'config_class', 'context_processor', 'create_global_jinja_loader', 'create_jinja_environment', 'create_url_adapter', 'debug', 'default_config', 'dispatch_request', 'do_teardown_appcontext', 'do_teardown_request', 'endpoint', 'env', 'error_handler_spec', 'errorhandler', 'extensions', 'finalize_request', 'full_dispatch_request', 'get_send_file_max_age', 'got_first_request', 'handle_exception', 'handle_http_exception', 'handle_url_build_error', 'handle_user_exception', 'has_static_folder', 'import_name', 'inject_url_defaults', 'instance_path', 'iter_blueprints', 'jinja_env', 'jinja_environment', 'jinja_loader', 'jinja_options', 'json_decoder', 'json_encoder', 'log_exception', 'logger', 'make_config', 'make_default_options_response', 'make_null_session', 'make_response', 'make_shell_context', 'name', 'open_instance_resource', 'open_resource', 'open_session', 'permanent_session_lifetime', 'preprocess_request', 'preserve_context_on_exception', 'process_response', 'propagate_exceptions', 'raise_routing_exception', 'register_blueprint', 'register_error_handler', 'request_class', 'request_context', 'response_class', 'root_path', 'route', 'run', 'save_session', 'secret_key', 'select_jinja_autoescape', 'send_file_max_age_default', 'send_static_file', 'session_cookie_name', 'session_interface', 'shell_context_processor', 'shell_context_processors', 'should_ignore_error', 'static_folder', 'static_url_path', 'subdomain_matching', 'teardown_appcontext', 'teardown_appcontext_funcs', 'teardown_request', 'teardown_request_funcs', 'template_context_processors', 'template_filter', 'template_folder', 'template_global', 'template_test', 'templates_auto_reload', 'test_cli_runner', 'test_cli_runner_class', 'test_client', 'test_client_class', 'test_request_context', 'testing', 'trap_http_exception', 'try_trigger_before_first_request_functions', 'update_template_context', 'url_build_error_handlers', 'url_default_functions', 'url_defaults', 'url_map', 'url_map_class', 'url_rule_class', 'url_value_preprocessor', 'url_value_preprocessors', 'use_x_sendfile', 'view_functions', 'wsgi_app']
```

Then now there's a lot of things that you usually need, and there's the `config` attribute.